# Subset and plot data frames with the same column names in ggplot in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, subset

I have a list of data frames in R. I would like to group them base on column names and plot the columns in separate plots. 
As sample, I just put the first 3 data frame :

```
     samp = list(`YUN_p07-i01_ClusterC2_ILA1` = structure(list(DLC12s = c(86.1999808927684, 
83.1661021183023, 83.1630245356896, 82.629186143684, 76.4255917126618, 
69.0475018007389, 66.6545180907876, 66.8711770634756, 68.8253794872399, 
68.7704831147614, 70.26250005327, 72.2278229651729, 74.4860838632999, 
77.1187068050456, 80.2289835630146, 83.5132828998463, 86.932579025573, 
90.0798627067643, 93.3213802621344, 96.3445845139445, 98.3384894630155, 
99.0003993047245), DLC17p = c(0.518445241686927, 1.50124229711346, 
1.53666803655824, 1.6104774860386, 2.18776070287186, 2.89527306653092, 
3.02632630555093, 3.02084155608756, 2.96675286121521, 2.96824532869834, 
2.92374876221941, 2.85102738508049, 2.74281718710316, 2.59153531461665, 
2.38055370716171, 2.11978801815047, 1.82682897488416, 1.52188989540395, 
1.17488046778467, 0.808365945518941, 0.503029623152029, 0.344992864013846
), DLC17q = c(0.29298751417293, 0.310534586369366, 0.310975265273449, 
0.308964093096275, 0.282724685666571, 0.243827177391463, 0.227830429978927, 
0.228345448650973, 0.241893146895052, 0.241682720609163, 0.252859420301516, 
0.266098094633695, 0.281076406680632, 0.299369324987808, 0.314254088328931, 
0.3279481386935, 0.340224557772322, 0.346805620741348, 0.350247337108639, 
0.351854889611391, 0.35031474482401, 0.348995199337251), DLC21gs = c(12.7175188616849, 
0.154406878557904, 0.159731563104607, 0.169321198108756, 0.267378128318265, 
0.397419705772557, 0.44521252330632, 0.452728605131062, 0.443770156726482, 
0.444584968615046, 0.434755098793551, 0.417971278512881, 0.395336173384056, 
0.368196278150562, 0.330177882848121, 0.288032267856803, 0.239930076244037, 
0.188873677400258, 0.129978946755775, 0.0701514631712911, 0.0251342731781843, 
0.00695036506137349), DLC24as = c(0.222826419796297, 0.241154083007526, 
0.242223080477684, 0.240731675193117, 0.226596554972244, 0.21240885403336, 
0.208095190949987, 0.21023410948102, 0.214507151215669, 0.214299097883211, 
0.216900688304365, 0.219479478428492, 0.224000630495338, 0.229218509216246, 
0.231508421326128, 0.234347481359479, 0.23588141958107, 0.236852522349953, 
0.235824289054205, 0.232912854777051, 0.228814319095028, 0.22741553913916
), DLC24bs = c(0.0277354272216626, 0.0417048470046467, 0.0411536057135019, 
0.0402770009471399, 0.0354691302004106, 0.0295040606839387, 0.028110042042609, 
0.0284524582542177, 0.0290303255956694, 0.0290063120570954, 0.0297072945388072, 
0.0301863940784852, 0.0307427943332238, 0.0314336800532286, 0.0321251759995036, 
0.0326178003245064, 0.0329001343436253, 0.0331890892391769, 0.0331135271129324, 
0.0327367223516411, 0.0321472514372787, 0.0315954058283562), 
    DLC31s = c(0.00179953374020422, 0.451788608573938, 0.442934432171455, 
    0.445622904440189, 0.436628281561018, 0.462579527770983, 
    0.510305042575961, 0.519610708797345, 0.498945044006626, 
    0.499611904183969, 0.482726079985608, 0.464696671845943, 
    0.444733898029508, 0.398150879001437, 0.352585611190157, 
    0.300299230995862, 0.250924147893593, 0.190372282644939, 
    0.132022999917796, 0.0682184829199272, 0.0248233408710608, 
    0.00694358215874919), DLC41es = c(0.000328145524310888, 0.00948175203382567, 
    0.00948726802358231, 0.00980032297688727, 0.0130918290429131, 
    0.0174977088332496, 0.0198021150412779, 0.0212155979227139, 
    0.0206450767247023, 0.0206726687032939, 0.0198417905459509, 
    0.0189240645299554, 0.0174068418749516, 0.0163555696797261, 
    0.0141781715845917, 0.0123311285214278, 0.0101624804251044, 
    0.0076012046350463, 0.00519505761737627, 0.00259807980889207, 
    0.000800681858654099, 0.000118165044984858), DLC41is = c(0.00114419563486984, 
    0.369375491856062, 0.365756142769149, 0.365996996068891, 
    0.43473253600147, 0.522486021253744, 0.566638554193928, 0.576048885109279, 
    0.545417828999124, 0.546148065430032, 0.520960004519625, 
    0.492548164103139, 0.444546226248173, 0.40764142578374, 0.354307810337745, 
    0.30349340919296, 0.230361604467185, 0.176334548654245, 0.109242958959919, 
    0.0548975677897042, 0.0164264438346333, 0.00246476685547599
    ), DLC41ms = c(0.0031633859810912, 0.121520954862548, 0.123617669347512, 
    0.129348870659286, 0.185113267199568, 0.260688273927753, 
    0.293583723552447, 0.297108478910199, 0.284979540913941, 
    0.285360416955637, 0.277273203197587, 0.265924489053568, 
    0.243859111154412, 0.229095516920215, 0.193723860107464, 
    0.169379206447382, 0.135389835451235, 0.107304402977301, 
    0.0753978064138843, 0.0389266842035347, 0.013348618834338, 
    0.00335417641912744), DLC64h = c(0.00343783271186764, 1.06349409996102, 
    1.04667922660965, 1.05739737426366, 1.2009737414251, 1.34198171391244, 
    1.41037653788597, 1.39843919377863, 1.31487869047025, 1.31707204759337, 
    1.24794982386622, 1.16244825009117, 1.05998107861483, 0.945539545735093, 
    0.810207490164157, 0.670470450823383, 0.52527828693085, 0.393307678470125, 
    0.253483138003207, 0.125592625134136, 0.0383912764363229, 
    0.00642030766889736), DLC64l = c(2.45692655312564e-16, 1.90268291100716, 
    1.90734606271009, 2.00968790284476, 3.15314431238807, 4.79594454391171, 
    5.29316146375101, 5.24590709808705, 4.85531024823933, 4.86232591566839, 
    4.5896820926463, 4.22177579070747, 3.85622595630147, 3.43124349080794, 
    2.92657229461866, 2.38158734440488, 1.82091534585416, 1.32811381255006, 
    0.834033610589599, 0.368749633593734, 0.0810811404823062, 
    0.00316209058271388), DLC72 = c(0.010632549076346, 10.6665113713504, 
    10.6504031115509, 10.9831880316785, 15.1507951176905, 19.7728875452393, 
    21.3160399803826, 21.129890796314, 19.7584904417584, 19.8005074388411, 
    18.7410956878111, 17.3610969737621, 15.7731898324797, 13.9335136600018, 
    11.8308219233181, 9.64642262338299, 7.41862411058014, 5.38949255816869, 
    3.34519959854764, 1.50041053717485, 0.347198822980415, 0.0171882331657344
    ), h = c(-52.5, -43.375, -34.25, -25.125, -16, -6.375, 3.25, 
    12.875, 22.5, 22.5, 29.467, 36.433, 43.4, 51.1, 58.8, 66.5, 
    74.2, 81.4, 88.6, 95.8, 103, 110.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L)), `SAM_p01-i01_B45-03` = structure(list(DLC12 = c(86.5314866162036, 
70.6482044279903, 70.0517266430886, 69.1537430043123, 67.8241590098885, 
66.7921442938182, 65.5937980140176, 64.3261418720238, 62.8913534820884, 
60.2489665221705, 56.6753714303144, 53.4520540590501, 50.3068923447928, 
48.3126391408391, 45.7382293718082, 44.108630511863, 43.321486762861, 
43.0602315026524, 43.0111480492834, 42.9379605954284, 42.9223167319234, 
42.8396978977298, 42.7920754385132, 42.7049422833556, 42.7031174954913, 
42.7102891219321, 42.6748905084158, 42.7650978277989, 43.0372974233205, 
43.4160213230891, 44.0275002603808, 44.9961254558944, 46.4686932865709, 
49.2809912275468, 55.0431218863332, 67.5331329321333, 88.8867737872429, 
99.4150369800821), DLC24a = c(0.218766367916309, 0.153340002337096, 
0.151650969728312, 0.149187928295569, 0.145890364320125, 0.143446126578526, 
0.140964905342863, 0.13812392978371, 0.135383865353581, 0.129413735907879, 
0.121387699080614, 0.113569036243044, 0.105845095969524, 0.100510612892751, 
0.0936069324743029, 0.0894943486944327, 0.0876085925358724, 0.0870050065625371, 
0.0869819496723875, 0.0868380015765139, 0.0868212695787194, 0.0866958376348893, 
0.086645708728405, 0.0865151999281387, 0.0865135517201478, 0.086534186426046, 
0.0865103663171702, 0.0869378045250614, 0.0879836961420589, 0.0894183411748553, 
0.0913138598157845, 0.0945822436516908, 0.0995456234554365, 0.109125877997524, 
0.127380884153403, 0.165166562786197, 0.224581307428501, 0.251060887424037
), DLC24b = c(0.0453214145449118, 0.0485214988383027, 0.0474234852066369, 
0.0459975660528709, 0.0439642773383507, 0.0424344466295988, 0.0406291833428262, 
0.0385910882375923, 0.0362724179811376, 0.0321579400348675, 0.0268641424420976, 
0.0224727618666185, 0.0186253035799354, 0.016430726972427, 0.0137797008874603, 
0.0122595872705079, 0.0116178253111307, 0.0114085223571877, 0.0113579355162143, 
0.0113600872937264, 0.0113676459438673, 0.0113948338535472, 0.011409838002603, 
0.0114454746305702, 0.011450626850776, 0.011457147558928, 0.0115163765216727, 
0.0116571243037127, 0.0118928895947969, 0.0122033597385413, 0.012615206546191, 
0.0132434489398068, 0.0142137755219769, 0.016076497250941, 0.019648872676804, 
0.0273543945082651, 0.0403086813652211, 0.0469900438394219), 
    DLC31 = c(0.114275756371283, 0.419696415865509, 0.418166663471472, 
    0.41659770277584, 0.412075330325881, 0.406296316875646, 0.404865668230333, 
    0.40199122147391, 0.397664754098204, 0.384758065118196, 0.359611489738715, 
    0.337066381557038, 0.31049067851873, 0.296809210627832, 0.277196869667497, 
    0.25971047000425, 0.249450511536022, 0.249950166945168, 0.249844869268875, 
    0.250428445647417, 0.251203765820931, 0.251349743180014, 
    0.252974109262994, 0.254301841336695, 0.2542961137628, 0.254257827350519, 
    0.254994504577032, 0.25585846552889, 0.257852426051227, 0.256590902847481, 
    0.255201118353802, 0.253687786597228, 0.249522336846397, 
    0.243218992806048, 0.221457233295584, 0.173167673208189, 
    0.0745166521363018, 0.0118927335597613), DLC41e = c(0.00112022892793795, 
    0.00529857259283213, 0.00513886656639065, 0.00513577550831923, 
    0.00498318974912717, 0.00480864175452075, 0.00470534905551177, 
    0.00454405919690493, 0.00433509316194446, 0.00405282002645228, 
    0.00364043874229719, 0.0034119775767327, 0.00328861599936114, 
    0.00312180175858676, 0.00310300107191918, 0.00313168682770946, 
    0.00308698623499945, 0.00313006479484543, 0.0031106433039962, 
    0.0031909369600748, 0.00319303983239588, 0.00319862778736807, 
    0.00325414565866252, 0.00329720389330231, 0.00329712683247052, 
    0.00329662311976585, 0.00338449846497849, 0.00342986707917998, 
    0.00344435269388162, 0.00355370257450106, 0.00356588396586719, 
    0.00357608951969794, 0.00364849556003587, 0.00365630346193987, 
    0.00353623622574113, 0.00306495528827925, 0.00187087677534341, 
    0.000767246364903308), DLC41i = c(0.138464782241703, 0.695771145407792, 
    0.678656847723093, 0.652820987658641, 0.614220855768878, 
    0.605164592690514, 0.589061464097191, 0.572828114303108, 
    0.558357480317725, 0.535805938686013, 0.503462966788739, 
    0.487773144497363, 0.467908482509039, 0.460694215981115, 
    0.45963949544064, 0.461477965786566, 0.469472540586466, 0.474132286796177, 
    0.475879264138292, 0.476130032032328, 0.476039141738809, 
    0.475900902572461, 0.476477622436718, 0.476544187858097, 
    0.476533064150817, 0.476514638318387, 0.478818676742515, 
    0.478351963263727, 0.476193805833404, 0.476028888774189, 
    0.472995262719091, 0.466040255253569, 0.455126942007137, 
    0.434475457645546, 0.390287233376125, 0.288899027555097, 
    0.106243915751312, 0.0059031597088719), DLC41m = c(0.02624806797749, 
    0.0910572322126005, 0.0910772065561211, 0.0910571646406683, 
    0.0922660406795948, 0.0938282326027338, 0.0930432613754086, 
    0.0942342368535042, 0.0950671623148232, 0.0968565540355199, 
    0.0991628672292148, 0.103129849170706, 0.10540808863291, 
    0.108077335190526, 0.111182242896488, 0.113356473143196, 
    0.117075597943824, 0.11764332028936, 0.117562270295499, 0.117469653538374, 
    0.117521497121909, 0.118157643858692, 0.120071400406781, 
    0.120418331734363, 0.120415520762977, 0.120397110727542, 
    0.121352538681384, 0.123711614322062, 0.123748714156593, 
    0.123947589454718, 0.124771697159254, 0.123833238508253, 
    0.121609278447632, 0.118496507991892, 0.108596794326569, 
    0.0844565328933596, 0.037930699698903, 0.0118228722878775
    ), DLC64h = c(0.0182870979585783, 0.0839347127169774, 0.0820496752995642, 
    0.0796857104239288, 0.076636326694896, 0.0740981166600861, 
    0.0721110662241128, 0.0702821912443217, 0.068262891201914, 
    0.0641913719951261, 0.0596382546252066, 0.055788498958326, 
    0.0524256485857287, 0.0506570165684668, 0.0488086020039789, 
    0.0479032070902036, 0.0472705352464485, 0.0472208188406132, 
    0.0469824183154683, 0.047018264107552, 0.0470103357329518, 
    0.0470375440907054, 0.0470562310613325, 0.0470744546889209, 
    0.0470743166442109, 0.0470768477898976, 0.0470842802403169, 
    0.0469135562298176, 0.0468468543689422, 0.0467067657278952, 
    0.0463100258520136, 0.0455636924415753, 0.0445267949801028, 
    0.0426557188239823, 0.038274989651877, 0.0283840679055483, 
    0.010545582038612, 0.000509047901546849), DLC64l = c(0.0775171406532654, 
    0.136702540728187, 0.142469508908647, 0.149231381067624, 
    0.161133814696488, 0.167862427276489, 0.17885757493889, 0.188322549460057, 
    0.202204943826697, 0.224182401507779, 0.254595240391027, 
    0.286367621990186, 0.321106527467607, 0.343385548016078, 
    0.368605928920641, 0.385543414984002, 0.396247373648929, 
    0.40012566445517, 0.401342670672085, 0.402437063371678, 0.402637227970377, 
    0.403164610194465, 0.403551159543014, 0.403880956940561, 
    0.403983023240631, 0.403923084291875, 0.404867616058887, 
    0.403980604314669, 0.402569298127318, 0.400532852311185, 
    0.397459089076149, 0.391746603729568, 0.381778845419467, 
    0.363069910185862, 0.322814659309606, 0.234950590644019, 
    0.0814069596737419, 0.00231177596624174), DLC72 = c(12.8285125272045, 
    27.7174734513101, 28.3316401334511, 29.256542779264, 30.6246707905386, 
    31.6699168051135, 32.8819635133752, 34.1649407374231, 35.6110979096556, 
    38.2796146505173, 41.8962654706474, 45.1383666690901, 48.3080092139444, 
    50.3076743911529, 52.8858478548286, 54.5184923343358, 55.2966832740955, 
    55.5491526463063, 55.5957899295336, 55.667166920044, 55.6818893443367, 
    55.7634023590981, 55.8064843463865, 55.8915800656335, 55.893319160544, 
    55.8862534124851, 55.9165806339803, 55.8240611726336, 55.5521705397113, 
    55.1749962743074, 54.5682675961309, 53.6116011854643, 52.161334621191, 
    49.3882335062894, 43.724881210651, 31.4614232630774, 10.535821537889, 
    0.253705252865466), h = c(-69.3, -65, -60, -55, -50, -47.5, 
    -45, -42.5, -39.9, -35.7, -30, -25, -20, -16.6, -11.5, -7, 
    -3.5, 0, 2.5, 6.5, 7.5, 11.5, 15, 21, 21.2, 21.2, 28.167, 
    35.133, 42.1, 48.26, 54.42, 60.58, 66.74, 73.94, 81.14, 88.34, 
    95.54, 102.74)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L)), `NnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36` = structure(list(DLC12 = c(54.4435251593895, 
60.4058230578194, 58.6303989612682, 55.314337253841, 50.7710434064941, 
46.4037703430297, 42.6359255249323, 40.3038329424453, 39.8819638103591, 
39.5582413841129, 39.2469336458061, 39.2393700712619, 38.9400585523699, 
38.8578597755466, 39.1476476831477, 39.8302872496507, 41.0591799377689, 
42.9639100534251, 45.8265164643939, 50.0114270438487, 57.5147424189172, 
71.1293758377103, 89.5087392552777, 97.8345822443614), DLC24a = c(0.159886150336981, 
0.171677716391787, 0.166377841964712, 0.156878943554993, 0.144906495222232, 
0.132883089000661, 0.122449254454408, 0.116110146641472, 0.115259375778084, 
0.114175047208234, 0.113332296094903, 0.113304603571124, 0.112510701057897, 
0.112551069962873, 0.113587724778825, 0.115526596882998, 0.11894812242382, 
0.124318407579698, 0.13248316606602, 0.143755537700758, 0.16258338643667, 
0.195528593960096, 0.235012447394, 0.249957876295005), DLC24b = c(0.0184136799547997, 
0.0292407180672802, 0.0281028927262214, 0.0255667376929854, 0.0215804758294541, 
0.017381680478672, 0.0140059337827739, 0.0118466008198282, 0.011287638730048, 
0.0112765092353713, 0.0112329422618099, 0.0112330297626183, 0.011237752427963, 
0.0112795563693597, 0.0113607823334111, 0.0115973921926224, 0.0119648096088683, 
0.012380757457651, 0.0131655540718474, 0.0141270419507646, 0.015891534764751, 
0.0188195794912396, 0.021878775274657, 0.0223137535322092), DLC31 = c(0.105191462635085, 
0.376068325580247, 0.376822148945267, 0.368943653977019, 0.33636158761232, 
0.284947878504001, 0.2400420288855, 0.20608995012619, 0.203680811762795, 
0.204922698290645, 0.206917758925312, 0.206942866445647, 0.208514117710556, 
0.213361180672979, 0.212624193011083, 0.210194540549773, 0.207716791456246, 
0.202430582734739, 0.19696461613771, 0.18522171342043, 0.162299056496549, 
0.118762287053893, 0.0497061292818597, 0.00895304495111956), 
    DLC41e = c(0.00199259615219407, 0.00993957948672134, 0.0101554562378574, 
    0.0101560159924302, 0.0106651651113587, 0.0104559651129055, 
    0.0106576811811128, 0.0108636812239941, 0.0110594342077646, 
    0.0110975125031564, 0.01114685873109, 0.0111482116879716, 
    0.0114046785560539, 0.0115137687759619, 0.0115393723104415, 
    0.0114074345887843, 0.0113445432723503, 0.0111061333243449, 
    0.0106024728241209, 0.009886717682106, 0.00858079186869025, 
    0.00619948404416043, 0.0024922245932218, 0.000480232404315263
    ), DLC41i = c(0.0763052952592319, 0.480698795794534, 0.484636373649032, 
    0.488443139980859, 0.484223512236868, 0.45008230602985, 0.416449313587552, 
    0.389629202260568, 0.375495512850925, 0.377397517190444, 
    0.381124504812132, 0.381170763638473, 0.383605301298594, 
    0.385283553119306, 0.383183928045964, 0.380587068011987, 
    0.372613918151571, 0.360618300981876, 0.342602503938473, 
    0.317236790747977, 0.27105301415066, 0.182777789727521, 0.0617505616005118, 
    0.00307815038496876), DLC41m = c(0.108423763069501, 0.213642296571627, 
    0.224021470123322, 0.235703458986629, 0.247437705979371, 
    0.255629062531108, 0.260051914144357, 0.263430377810683, 
    0.264315432068389, 0.265150461368426, 0.265787300849609, 
    0.265818825867519, 0.269749171357754, 0.270860446221749, 
    0.269684829550434, 0.267126140943506, 0.263919871046971, 
    0.256284443998711, 0.245964175707705, 0.22687385585044, 0.19454871946828, 
    0.133912779773782, 0.049586430015697, 0.0104269884192644), 
    DLC64h = c(0.0682039035949202, 0.383871502474758, 0.388491367390502, 
    0.395755233673989, 0.393883110591027, 0.38357754392518, 0.371192627641175, 
    0.35879623584899, 0.352773981770983, 0.354202342501633, 0.356355111673662, 
    0.356394798433093, 0.358206787817173, 0.358829611133505, 
    0.356503939797175, 0.352564074882189, 0.344411784577679, 
    0.33324366230195, 0.315954338887504, 0.291798989347465, 0.248258599757461, 
    0.167373696825949, 0.0562840185760291, 0.00259384825815647
    ), DLC64l = c(0.0491324764617038, 0.000646464542124482, 0.000667879850640206, 
    0.000701790359459709, 0.000841724333258625, 0.00114200742199224, 
    0.00131740059947369, 0.00136310896030365, 0.00144901162200778, 
    0.00145565011406664, 0.00145811522861758, 0.00145829151877925, 
    0.00147135248013787, 0.00147067631008413, 0.00146381996555089, 
    0.00144440003600201, 0.00141179438808945, 0.00136721892293532, 
    0.00130176688585897, 0.00120290010563353, 0.00102531633992181, 
    0.000721485552802989, 0.000232649267060849, 1.06783775639768e-05
    ), DLC72 = c(8.336495144341, 36.1745297466092, 38.0024519770216, 
    41.4219739594744, 46.169603890161, 50.8277951216586, 54.8483955416169, 
    57.3059654863845, 57.6667222086439, 57.9424246003873, 58.1910628562599, 
    58.1986690819518, 58.4265648533366, 58.4351633910753, 58.0802412959206, 
    57.3306586991926, 56.0356771397037, 54.0588453495766, 51.1170782368227, 
    46.8800604490026, 39.3644742856029, 25.8834017175556, 7.9801308355807, 
    0.195382722914001), DLCE4 = c(31.8570261713385, 0.25009748180922, 
    0.209897168793501, 0.15484791604718, 0.0948240785715274, 
    0.0614002092775255, 0.0563958701235407, 0.0684838817269651, 
    0.0892028748168604, 0.0998945161796054, 0.112021762835994, 
    0.111909788729208, 0.124743055773804, 0.141123311513771, 
    0.159835345537721, 0.182104148939161, 0.210188267147751, 
    0.246003670536013, 0.294870716758041, 0.357366008233493, 
    0.462384124454952, 0.664148164486512, 0.979121056602319, 
    1.16907226723123), DLCE7 = c(4.77540419746678, 1.50376431485265, 
    1.47797646202944, 1.42669189641922, 1.32462884785723, 1.17093479302985, 
    1.02311690905089, 0.963588385751101, 1.02678990738926, 1.05976176090831, 
    1.10262684652118, 1.10257966713171, 1.15193367581346, 1.20070365929903, 
    1.25232708560117, 1.30650225412976, 1.36262302045392, 1.42949141916033, 
    1.50249598750593, 1.56104295210936, 1.59415875174203, 1.49897858381782, 
    1.05506561653598, 0.503148192870783), h = c(-75.4, -66, -56.6, 
    -47.2, -37.8, -28.35, -18.9, -9.45, 0, 6.25, 12.5, 12.5, 
    19.467, 26.433, 33.4, 40.96, 48.52, 56.08, 63.64, 70.84, 
    78.04, 85.24, 92.44, 99.64)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L)))
```

Looking at the column names we have :

```
coln = lapply(samp, names)
coln
$`YUN_p07-i01_ClusterC2_ILA1`
 [1] "DLC12s"  "DLC17p"  "DLC17q"  "DLC21gs" "DLC24as" "DLC24bs" "DLC31s"  "DLC41es" "DLC41is" "DLC41ms" "DLC64h"  "DLC64l"  "DLC72"  
[14] "h"      

$`SAM_p01-i01_B45-03`
 [1] "DLC12"  "DLC24a" "DLC24b" "DLC31"  "DLC41e" "DLC41i" "DLC41m" "DLC64h" "DLC64l" "DLC72"  "h"     

$`NnG_p24-i02_c02_6P_M36`
 [1] "DLC12"  "DLC24a" "DLC24b" "DLC31"  "DLC41e" "DLC41i" "DLC41m" "DLC64h" "DLC64l" "DLC72"  "DLCE4"  "DLCE7"  "h"
```

`h` is height and is presented in all dataframes.
 I'm looking for a clean way to subset all the columns with the same name in one separate data frame.

```
ind = as.data.frame(table(unlist(coln)))
ind
      Var1 Freq
1    DLC12    2
2   DLC12s    1
3   DLC17p    1
4   DLC17q    1
5  DLC21gs    1
6   DLC24a    2
7  DLC24as    1
8   DLC24b    2
9  DLC24bs    1
10   DLC31    2
11  DLC31s    1
12  DLC41e    2
13 DLC41es    1
14  DLC41i    2
15 DLC41is    1
16  DLC41m    2
17 DLC41ms    1
18  DLC64h    3
19  DLC64l    3
20   DLC72    3
21   DLCE4    1
22   DLCE7    1
23       h    3
```

In this case I need 22 data frame. More specific, the column name `DLC64h` is present in all data frames so my subset should have 6 column for the `DLC64h` and its related `h`.
The following just works if my selected column name in repreated in all data frames :

```
d1 = lapply(samp, function(x) x[, c(as.character(ind[18,1]),"h")])
```

But not in case it is not a common column name.

After selecting those subsets I have to plot them. One plot per unique column name.

Comment: 22, `h` is the variable that I need to plot all the other column names based on that. So I need to plot all the unique col.names based on their `h` values

Comment: exactely, if you look at something like `d1` in my example, the same col.name from different data.frame in the list do not have the same length. I don't know something like `NA` should be good I assume, Since I have to plot them at the end

Comment: @akrun So, `h` is unique in each data.frame. in this example I have 3 dataframe in the list with 3 `h` which are different . in case we would like to plot a column which is repeated in each data.frame , let say `DLC64h` we have to plot 3 pair of data : `DLC64h` and `h` from the first data.frame, `DLC64h` and `h` from the second dataframe and `DLC64h` and `h` from the third data.frame.

Comment: @akrun, True ! if you look at `ind` object in my example, it says in the list , 2 data.frames has a column called `DLC12` , 3 data.frame that has a column called `DLC64h` and so on. What is needed now is a plot each unique col.name. If it is repeated once , so it is just one plot of that col.name against the h. if it is more than one time repeated, then like `DLC12`, it should be 2 curve in the plot one in `DLC12` and `h` from the second data.frame in the list and one `DLC12` and `h` from the 3rd data.frame in the list

Comment: @akrun correct ! the plot name should be `DLC31` and the legend are `2` and `3`

Comment: @akrun `package ‘rowr’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)`

Comment: @akrun this is do the selection but I don't know why it is ignoring the `h` : `d = list()

for(i in 1:(dim(ind)[1]-1)){
  d[[i]] = lapply(samp, function(x) ifelse(ind[i,1] %in% colnames(x),x[, c(as.character(ind[i,1]),"h")] , NA))
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the `unique` column names from all the `list` elements ('un1'), loop over the names, extract the column names that are the same from each of the 'samp' in a nested `lapply`, use `cbind.fill` from `rowr` to `cbind` the `list` elements (while `fill`ing the unequal rows with NA for those datasets that have less number of rows) to create 'lst1'.  Another `list` is created to get the index the `list` element where the column names comes from ('lst2').  Use these two lists in `Map` to extract the corresponding 'h' column based on the index from 'lst2', and `cbind` with each of the datasets of 'lst1'

```
library(rowr)
un1 <- setdiff(unique(unlist(lapply(samp, names))), "h")     
lst1 <-  lapply(un1, function(nm) do.call(cbind.fill,
   c(Filter(length, lapply(samp, function(x)
        x[colnames(x) == nm])), fill = NA)))
lst2 <- lapply(un1, function(nm) which(do.call(c,
     lapply(samp, function(x)  any(names(x) == nm)))))
out <- Map(function(dat1, ind) {
      tmp <- do.call(cbind.fill, c(lapply(samp[ind], `[[`, 'h'), fill = NA))
      names(tmp) <- paste0("h", seq_along(tmp))
      cbind(dat1, tmp)},
       lst1, lst2)

length(out)
#[1] 22
```

-checking the output

```
lapply(out, head, 2)
#[[1]]
#    DLC12s      h1
#1 86.19998 -52.500
#2 83.16610 -43.375

#[[2]]
#     DLC17p      h1
#1 0.5184452 -52.500
#2 1.5012423 -43.375

#[[3]]
#     DLC17q      h1
#1 0.2929875 -52.500
#2 0.3105346 -43.375

#[[4]]
#     DLC21gs      h1
#1 12.7175189 -52.500
#2  0.1544069 -43.375

#[[5]]
#    DLC24as      h1
#1 0.2228264 -52.500
#2 0.2411541 -43.375

#[[6]]
#     DLC24bs      h1
#1 0.02773543 -52.500
#2 0.04170485 -43.375

#[[7]]
#       DLC31s      h1
#1 0.001799534 -52.500
#2 0.451788609 -43.375

#[[8]]
#       DLC41es      h1
#1 0.0003281455 -52.500
#2 0.0094817520 -43.375

#[[9]]
#      DLC41is      h1
#1 0.001144196 -52.500
#2 0.369375492 -43.375

#[[10]]
#      DLC41ms      h1
#1 0.003163386 -52.500
#2 0.121520955 -43.375

#[[11]]
#       DLC64h     DLC64h    DLC64h      h1    h2    h3
#1 0.003437833 0.01828710 0.0682039 -52.500 -69.3 -75.4
#2 1.063494100 0.08393471 0.3838715 -43.375 -65.0 -66.0

#[[12]]
#        DLC64l     DLC64l       DLC64l      h1    h2    h3
#1 2.456927e-16 0.07751714 0.0491324765 -52.500 -69.3 -75.4
#2 1.902683e+00 0.13670254 0.0006464645 -43.375 -65.0 -66.0

#[[13]]
#        DLC72    DLC72     DLC72      h1    h2    h3
#1  0.01063255 12.82851  8.336495 -52.500 -69.3 -75.4
#2 10.66651137 27.71747 36.174530 -43.375 -65.0 -66.0

#[[14]]
#     DLC12    DLC12    h1    h2
#1 86.53149 54.44353 -69.3 -75.4
#2 70.64820 60.40582 -65.0 -66.0

#[[15]]
#     DLC24a    DLC24a    h1    h2
#1 0.2187664 0.1598862 -69.3 -75.4
#2 0.1533400 0.1716777 -65.0 -66.0

#[[16]]
#      DLC24b     DLC24b    h1    h2
#1 0.04532141 0.01841368 -69.3 -75.4
#2 0.04852150 0.02924072 -65.0 -66.0

#[[17]]
#      DLC31     DLC31    h1    h2
#1 0.1142758 0.1051915 -69.3 -75.4
#2 0.4196964 0.3760683 -65.0 -66.0

#[[18]]
#       DLC41e      DLC41e    h1    h2
#1 0.001120229 0.001992596 -69.3 -75.4
#2 0.005298573 0.009939579 -65.0 -66.0

#[[19]]
#     DLC41i    DLC41i    h1    h2
#1 0.1384648 0.0763053 -69.3 -75.4
#2 0.6957711 0.4806988 -65.0 -66.0

#[[20]]
#      DLC41m    DLC41m    h1    h2
#1 0.02624807 0.1084238 -69.3 -75.4
#2 0.09105723 0.2136423 -65.0 -66.0

#[[21]]
#       DLCE4    h1
#1 31.8570262 -75.4
#2  0.2500975 -66.0

#[[22]]
#     DLCE7    h1
#1 4.775404 -75.4
#2 1.503764 -66.0
```

---

If we don't have `rowr`, then an option is to create rows for the `list` elements that have less number of rows with `NA`

```
un1 <- setdiff(unique(unlist(lapply(samp, names))), "h")   
lst1 <- lapply(un1, function(nm)  {
  tmplst <- Filter(length, lapply(samp, function(x) 
      x[colnames(x) == nm]))
  mx <- max(sapply(tmplst, nrow))
  do.call(cbind, lapply(tmplst, function(x) {
        if(mx > nrow(x))  x[nrow(x):mx, ] <- NA
       x}))})

 lst2 <- lapply(un1, function(nm) which(do.call(c,
       lapply(samp, function(x)  any(names(x) == nm)))))


out <- Map(function(dat1, ind) {
      tmplst <-  lapply(samp[ind], `[[`, 'h')
      mx <- max(lengths(tmplst))
      tmplst1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(tmplst, `length<-`, mx))
      colnames(tmplst1) <- paste0('h', seq_len(ncol(tmplst1)))
      cbind(dat1, tmplst1)
      }, lst1, lst2)



sapply(out, dim)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] #[,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
#[1,]   22   22   22   22   22   22   22   22   22    22    38    38    38    38    #38    38    38    38    38    38
#[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2     6     6     6     4     #4     4     4     4     4     4
#     [,21] [,22]
#[1,]    24    24
#[2,]     2     2
```

#### Update

With the named `list`, we can change the

```
 colnames(tmplst1) <- paste0('h', seq_len(ncol(tmplst1)))
```

to

```
colnames(tmplst1) <- paste0('h', colnames(tmplst1))
```

ie.

```
out <- Map(function(dat1, ind) {
   tmplst <-  lapply(samp[ind], `[[`, 'h')
   mx <- max(lengths(tmplst))
   tmplst1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(tmplst, `length<-`, mx))
   colnames(tmplst1) <- paste0('h', colnames(tmplst1))
   cbind(dat1, tmplst1)
    }, lst1, lst2)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213660/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-subset-and-plot-data-frames-with-the-same-column-n).